# Android: Sending data to be stored in MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

**Solved:** Was missing view parameter for postData(), changed to reflect this.

I would like some help with sending GPS data to a server which will be stored in a MySQL database using PHP.

This is inside my Java file:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

public void postData(View v)
{
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lat","19.80"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lon","13.22"));

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new      
        HttpPost("http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/test.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }           
}
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php'; //Connect

//retrieve the data
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lon = $_POST['lon'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Coords (Lat, Lon) VALUES('$lat', '$lon')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $sqlCon))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    //echo "1 record added";
}

include 'closeConnection.php';
?>
```

StackTrace:
    Project - Heat [Android Application]

```
 02-06 00:37:14.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-06 00:37:14.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1607): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could       
 not find a method **postData(View)** in the activity class com.nathanhunston.heat.Main for   
 onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'dropLocBtn'
```

Comment: You should check your logcat output and post the stacktrace here.

Comment: @dave.c Posted the trace, from what I can see right away I have an illegalStateException, so something to do with the virtual machine not being in the correct state....

Comment: I don't think that's your log logcat output.  You can use either the view in eclipse, or the standalone tool to get the output.  Have a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html) for details.

Comment: @dave.c yeah you were right my logcat had broken when the emulator crashed, ill post the log now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line of your stack trace tells you exactly what you are doing wrong:

```
02-06 00:37:14.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 00:37:14.265: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1607): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method postData(View) in the activity class com.nathanhunston.heat.Main for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'dropLocBtn'
```

That is because you do not have a `View` parameter in your `postData()` method declaration.

Comment: @Herly: Yeah, sometimes I wish there were a direct neural interface from LogCat straight to my brain. OTOH, LogCat is rather chatty, and the other voices inside my head will get jealous.

Comment: And we would want that now would we.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` to the manifest.xml?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to send GPS coords to a database to be stored, I can access the location, I am just having a real headache sending any form of data to the server.

Comment: Yeah what... have you got that line in your manifest?

Check the Logcat for a stacktrace under the Debug perspective and post it.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, yes I have the line in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call it in a **thread**... if the server hangs a little bit to respond, you get *Force close* messages...

You can look at this post: [Problem with Android HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277077/problem-with-android-http-post)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that in line  "**nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lat","19.80"));**"  you have used **Lat** and in line **$_POST['lat'];**,  you have used **lat**.  so Lat and lat are different thing. By the way, here is good article, http://androidtheme.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/connect-android-device-to-mysql/. It really works, i hope you like it.